# What are the current possibilities for infinite-dimensional manifolds?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, frechet-manifold, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

According to wikipedia, by a theorem of Henderson '69, infinite-dimensional [Frechet Manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_manifold) embed as open subspaces of Hilbert Space. They need to be seperable & metric. They are generalisations of [Banach Manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_manifold), so they too have the same property.

Michor & Krigel, say 'this does not make them [Banach Manifolds] interesting [enough]' in [The convenient setting of Global Analysis](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf),

What are the other directions to take, when looking for interesting infinite-dimensional manifolds, (besides the one Michor/Kriegel outline in their book). And has a canonical choice begun to establish itself yet?

Comment: I don't understand what this question is about: What would you consider to be interesting and what would be a canonical choice for what end? Possibilities for what? Moreover, Henderson's result says that *if* a Fréchet manifold is separable and metrizable *then* it embeds as an open subset into $\ell_2$. Finally, what exactly is the difference between the present question and your earlier question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90656?

Comment: Your question appears to me to be along the lines of "tell me something about infinite dimensional manifolds", in that it's rather undirected and unmotivated.   

Comment: @user49437: my first question was reacting against Michors assertion that Banach Manifolds aren't interesting. Obviously they're not flexible enough notion for the purposes he wants to put them to. 

Comment: @Ryan: I'd agree it isn't focused enough, but I'd dispute its unmotivated.

Comment: @Martin: It's what Michor et al was saying about Banach manifolds that made them uninteresting. Not me. I didn't know enough then to form a judgement. It's seems pretty silly to me to knock back a question which is asking about more informed judgement.

Comment: @Ryan Budney: See above. A focused question on a certain field would entail already knowing a great deal about that field. These aren't the questions that one asks when one is first entering a field. Banach manifolds are an easy enough generalisation of ordinary manifolds. Lang for ecample defines them.  So it's useful to know why they aren't 'interesting' to the cognescenti.

Comment: I think the point is that Banach manifolds were thought to perhaps give some new interesting structure that could be taken advantage of.  But Henderson's theorem could be seen as a rebuttal.  If we want additional structure we need to be purposeful in creating it, rather than just mimicking what is intellectually convenient.